# Rsync ssh dest folder bigger than source folder

Tags: backup, rsync

I want to do a backup of all my files from my linux computer to a ssh server. I used rsync with :

> rsync -rl source dest

But now the dest folder (which was empty before) is larger than the source. why? How can i be sure that everything is ok?

Comment: How did you measure the size of the source and target? Are you copying to the same kind of file system? Are there hard links in the source directory (you need `-H` to keep them as hard links)? Did you run `rsync` only once or repeat it during a few days?

Comment: acctually it's not my data, it's the computer from a former employee and i just make a backup before delete the data. Indeed i don't thought about that but there are some hardlinks